# How to correlate a ten category variable?

Tags: spss

Suppose we have a categorical variable X which can take on 10 values. There are counts inside each of these 10 categories. I want to see whether there are correlations between categories. How would I do this in SPSS? Is there a way to split X into 10 subvariables?

I go to **Analyze ---> Correlate --->  Bivariate** and can only find the variable X (not the 10 categories).

Comment: What do you mean by correlations between categories?

Comment: Bivariate correlations are typicalle done between variables.
I am unable to understand your data structure - maybe it would be possible to dichotimize the data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a single variable with mutually exclusive categories. If this is the case then if the variable equals a particular category, then that means it does not equal any other category. Therefore, it makes no sense to correlate such a variable.

If you do not have mutually exclusive categories (i.e., you have what is sometimes called a multi-variable) then your 10 response options would be represented as 10 separate variables in SPSS. You could then potentially use `Analyze - correlate - bivariate` to examine relationships between category co-occurrence.